# Cómo insertar un div entre dos divs que se van a generar por JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Este pedazo de código me trae de otras variables una lista de arreglos que acomodo por acá, las imprimo en los divs y se acomodan en la pagina, lo que quiero es que de la misma manera que imprimo estos divs con los arreglos, después de cada 5 divs que imprima me imprima un 6to pero que este sea por ejemplo una linea y después seguir con el resto de los divs y que cuando vuelvan a ser 5 mas se imprima de nuevo esta linea

```
 .success(function(data)
      {

            console.log(data.Resultado.Nombre);
            console.log(data.Resultado.IdCategoria);
            console.log(data.Resultado.Imagen);
            var test = data.Resultado.Nombre;
            var test1 = data.Resultado.Imagen;
            var test2 = data.Resultado.IdCategoria;
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(test, function(i, data) {
                    trHTML += '  < div class = "cat_col \"> < img src = imgs / ' + test1[i] + '.jpg / > < h4 > ' + test[i] + ' < /h4> < /div >
                        ';
                    if (condicion) {
                        $("div.class_col").insertBefore(' < div class = "border_bottom border_gray desktop_only" > < /div>
                            ')
                        }
                    }); $('#categorias').append(trHTML);
            })
```

Comment: Perdón, pero insertBefore no necesita un nodo como elemento? Ahí le estás pasando un string.

Comment: La pregunta está confusa y el código tiene algunos errores. Por favor, rectificalos

Comment: es bien difícil esta comunidad

Comment: @Godeolo esta dificil ya que la idea es ir mejorando con el tiempo la comunidad. Es mucho mas facil ayudarte cuando tu codigo es entendible, legible y bien explicado. Debes entender que tenemos que ponernos en tu contexto y en tu manera de programar. Es muy importante ir mejorando las preguntas para asi tener respuestas mucho mejores y seamos todos un aporte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres agregar cada 6 `<div>` otro mas debes contarlos.

```
var contador = 1;
$.each(test, function(i, data) {
       //sumas tus divs a tus variables
       if(contador == 6){
           //Aqui a tu variable que suma los divs como texto, agregale tu div con el separador que quieres. Y luego el contador lo inicializas nuevamente en 1.
           contador = 1;
       }
       contador++;
})
```